# How to handle keyboard events in subclass of NSViewController?

Tags: cocoa, event-handling, nsviewcontroller

I am creating one cocoa application having wizard like structure.

All dialogs are subclass of NSViewController. Currently I am not able get keyboard events such as keyDown and keyUp..

Please help me to solve this problem....

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4):

Override keyDown: and  keyUp: method.

```
-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent*)event
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)event
```

and

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

In subclass of `NSViewController` 
you should refer [Cocoa Event-Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html) .

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to simply get an event for escape, use this instead:

```
override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}

override func cancelOperation(_ sender: Any?) {
    // The user pressed escape
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting window to "Auto Recalculates View Loop" in Inteface Builder has worked for me.