# keyDown(with:) Not Called on Custom ViewController or View, Only WindowController

Tags: cocoa, nsview, xcode-storyboard, nswindowcontroller, keyboard-input

I have moved most of the core functionality of my non-document based macOS app to a custom, embedded framework.

The app code has a standard main storyboard with an initial window, and the window has a "window content" relationship/segue into a storyboard reference pointing to a storyboard inside the embedded framework. Therein lies a custom `NSViewController` subclass and a custom `NSView` subclass.

I want to group all the input event handling code inside the framework, which means implementing `mouseDown(with:)` on the custom `NSView` subclass, and --lo and behold-- it gets called when I click inside the app window. So far, so good.

**Next,** I implemented `keyDown(with:)` to similarly handle keyboard input. However, at runtime, it does not get called and instead, I hear the annoying beep (`NSBeep`).

I tried implementing `keyDown(with:)` **on the view controller** instead, but it's all the same.

Finally, I tried implementing the key handler on my `NSWindowController` subclass instead, and that *does* work.

So I *could* get around this by forwarding the event like so:

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        contentViewController?.view.keyDown(with: event)
    }
}
```

, but it is very inelegant. I would prefer to not pollute the app code with input logic.

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with embedding frameworks, however. [I put together a minimal project](https://github.com/nicolas-miari/Cocoa-KeyDown-Demo) from the 'Cocoa App' template and confirmed that indeed `keyDown(with:)` only gets called if implemented on the *window controller* code, but *not* on the *view* or *view controller* side.

**How can I get `keyDown(with:)` to be called on the view or view controller (not the window or window controller) in a storyboard-based app?** (so I can move it from the main app to my embedded framework).

---

**Edit:** The question has been marked as duplicate. I tried the solutions pointed in answers to the other question (namely, override `acceptsFirstResponder` to return `true`). This solves the problem in my minimal demo project, but when I tried it on my full app, it still does not work (I did see that question and did try to override `acceptsFirstResponder` in my app before posting this question).

I will now try to modify my minimal poeject to see if I can reporduce the issue in the main app.

---

**Edit 2:** I have refactored the minimal project to:

1. Send the view controller to  a separate storyboard,
2. Send the view controller's storyboard and represented classes (custom view, custom view controller) to a separate, embedded framework.

Now the basic setup **mirrors that of my app** in all that seems to matter, but still can not reproduce the issue in the minimal project. I will investiate further...

---

**Edit 3:** I haven't been able to reproduce the issue on the minimal project.
On my app's custom view, I implemented:

```
public override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}

public override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
    let retVal = super.performKeyEquivalent(with: event)
    return retVal
}
```

1. On startup, `acceptsFirstResponder` is called twice.
2. When hitting any key, `performKeyEquivalent(with:)` is called twice, too. Inspectig the intermediate variable `retVal` above reveals that the super class's implementation always returns `false`. After returning from this method, `NSBeep()` is called and `keyDown(with:)` isn't.
3. If instead of `super.performKeyEquivalent(with:)` I force-return `true`, I can avert the call to `NSBeep()` (but `keyDown(with:)` is still not called...)

---

**Edit 4 (Final):**

Out of desperation, I cleared the "Custom Class" field of the window controller's **Identity Inspector** in my app's main storyboard (to the default `NSWindowController`).

**Suddenly**, my custom view's `keyDown(with:)` starts getting called.

I reinstated the custom class to confirm.

**It still works**.

I clean the build folder and try again.

**It still works**.

Now I can no longer reproduce the issue even on my main app. I really don't know what to say...

Comment: Keydown events are sent tot the first responder. See [The Path of Key Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Capture keydown from NSViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446978/swift-capture-keydown-from-nsviewcontroller)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift NSViewController responds to mouseDown event, but not keyDown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723756/swift-nsviewcontroller-responds-to-mousedown-event-but-not-keydown-event)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle keyboard events in subclass of NSViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148714/how-to-handle-keyboard-events-in-subclass-of-nsviewcontroller)

Comment: @Willeke see my edits.